# Do I need to format my SD card before imaging Raspbian to it?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

My question:

Do I need to format my SD card for my before imaging Raspbian to it?

Raspbian is already flashed on the card but I want to start with a fresh OS.
I'm using Win32 Disk Imager.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably not (unless the card is corrupt). Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, i tried it, and the FAT32-partition is readable by Windows.
But i haven't tried it in the Pi yet.

Comment: It's not necessary to format the SD card, but it takes a few seconds and could potentially save you some headaches. In my experience using Windows to format SD cards, the best thing to do is to select restore device defaults. You are then set to image the SD card. The process for re-imaging a SD card is a little different however.

Comment: Thank you very much both! Now i know that i don't have to format it before writing an image on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Writing an image to the SD Card (or any other storage device) using `dd` or disk imaging software does a low level block copy and will totally overwrite any contents (including boot sector, partition table and any partitions).

You can format, if you like, but this is just another unnecessary write cycle to the card.

If you want to install NOOBS or [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) the card needs to be formatted as `FAT`.